# How to remove line from patch script

Tags: patches, ssh

When I run a patch it fails on one of the files. I would like to remove the respective line from the patch.x.x.x.sh so everything else is being patched except this file.

Hope someone can explain the procedure.

For example, I am trying to apply Patch SUPEE-10336 and get error:

```
[http]$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
Hunk #1 FAILED at 99.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv.rej
```

I would like to edit the `PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh` so I remove the line from the patch that's responsible for this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anyone interested in this question but I thought I post the answer to it anyway.

If you open the patch in any text editor, and find the section `__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__` that's where the files are being merged using `diff` command. In make case it was the `Mage_Usa.csv" file was causing the problem so I found the part of the patch responsible for this file:

```
diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
index 072170d..5e8f844 100644
--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
 "First-Class Mail Large Envelope","First-Class Mail Large Envelope"
 "First-Class Mail Large Postcards","First-Class Mail Large Postcards"
 "First-Class Mail Letter","First-Class Mail Letter"
-"First-Class Mail Parcel","First-Class Mail Parcel"
+"First-Class Package Service - Retail","First-Class Package Service - Retail"
 "First-Class Mail Postcards","First-Class Mail Postcards"
 "First-Class Package International Service","First-Class Package International Service"
 "First-Class Package Service","First-Class Package Service"
```

I have deleted this whole section of the patch and re-run it is SSH.

This time:

```
[http]$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

I have manually changed the USPS names in file `Mage_Usa.csv` (The part of the patch that I deleted).